# How to disable error squiggles for Python in Visual Studio (2017)

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, customization, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to disable Intellisense error marks for Python in Visual Studio 2017? Other languages appear to be capable of this by navigating to..

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> *Language Type* -> ***** -> Squiggles`

But I can't seem to find anything to disable these for Python. If anyone knows how to completely disable squiggles for all languages, that would be helpful as well.

I'm hoping I'm just overlooking the setting. But in case its not possible, there is one crazy solution for anyone really wanting to get rid of them - navigate to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors`, and change the color of `Syntax Error` to match your background. It's a bit extreme, but the only way I've found to do it so far. I've been saving this as an alternate theme for Python so I can switch back and forth easily.

However, I'm hoping there is an actual setting for this somewhere?